# Create a gif from an array of bitmap vb.net (visual studio 2013)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, gif

My goal is to creat a gif from (42) images that I got (screenshots from a graphic after a small rotation).
I managed to find some ways to do it, but each time I must instal some package/component/library (I'm not familiar with those...)
A gif is a succession of images right? Isn't there a easy way to "stick" those image on after an other as a gif? Or there is nothing in visual studio for that (I found somewhere in the project tab ---> add a component ---> image.gif but i can't manage to do anything with it)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapencoder_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Check this out: [Extract Images From Animated Gif](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/254919-extract-images-from-animated-gif/) or this [How to: Encode and Decode a GIF Image @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970565(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Take a look: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET

Comment: Are you trying to make an animated gif or a single image gif that is a collage of several bitmap images (each shown adjacent to each other)?